# I need help with uv editor

Tags: uv-image-editor

I want to create a texture on a plane but after creating a second uv map for the other side idk how to scale it right. The back texture is on the same image also. i need to know how i can make it fit.

This is the texture https://www.textures.com/download/3datlas0401/138065?q=Nettle

and here is my file: https://ufile.io/p5ztw7p0

sorry for my bad english

Comment: I think to have separate front and back sides, you will need to create a shader that uses the 'backfacing' output of the 'geometry' node to switch between two different textures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what the question is, but give this solution a try.

Go into edit mode, select all the vertices of your mesh with the A key, split the view to where you have a uv editor window, and the 3D view window, then, in the uv editor window, select all the vertices, s key to scale.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am sorry my English is really not the best... what i wanted to know is how i can put the texture 100%  on top of each other.  like here https://prnt.sc/ou4k6n

Comment: When i scale it there is always something wrong

Comment: In the UV editor: select all the UV's you want to mirror. To flip them horizontally, tap the S key, the "-", then the "1" key, and press enter. Then select the islands one at a tI'm and move them into position. To scale them, tap the S key again and move the mouse until it looks right (if you already scaled the other isands before mirroring, should fit without needing to scale.